# Sorting by value returned by a function in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a function that returns a value and displays a similarity between tracks, i want the returned result to be ordered by this returned value, but i cannot figure out a way on how to do it, here is what i have already tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_list_similar_tracks(frstTrack IN tracks.track_id%TYPE)
AS
  sim number;
  res tracks%rowtype;
  chosenTrack tracks%rowtype;

BEGIN
select * into chosenTrack from tracks where track_id = frstTrack;
dbms_output.put_line('similarity between');
FOR res IN (select * from tracks WHERE ROWNUM <= 10)LOOP
    SELECT * INTO sim FROM ( SELECT func_similarity(frstTrack, res.track_id)from dual order by sim)  order by sim; //that's where i am getting the value and where i am trying to order

    dbms_output.put_line( chosenTrack.track_name || '(' ||frstTrack|| ') and ' ||     res.track_name || '(' ||res.track_id|| ') ---->' ||  sim);
END LOOP;
END proc_list_similar_tracks;

/
declare
begin
proc_list_similar_tracks(437830);
end;
/
```

no errors are given, the list is just presented unsorted, is it not possible to order by a value that was returned by a function? if so, how do i accomplish something like this? or am i just doing something horribly wrong?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In the interests of (over-)optimisation I would avoid ordering by a function if I could possibly avoid it; especially one that queries other tables. If you're querying a table you should be able to add that part to your current query, which enables you to use it normally.

However, let's look at your function:

1. There's no point using `DBMS_OUTPUT` for anything but debugging *unless* you're going to be there looking at exactly what is output *every* time the function is run; you could remove these lines.
2. The following is used only for a `DBMS_OUTPUT` and is therefore an unnecessary SELECT and can be removed:

   ```
   select * into chosenTrack from tracks where track_id = frstTrack;
   ```
3. You're selecting a random 10 rows from the table TRACKS; why?

   ```
   FOR res IN (select * from tracks WHERE ROWNUM <= 10)LOOP
   ```
4. Your ORDER BY, `order by sim`, is ordering by a non-existent column as the column SIM hasn't been declared within the scope of the SELECT
5. Your ORDER BY is asking for the *least* similar as the default sort order is ascending (this may be correct but it seems wrong?)
6. Your function is not a function, it's a procedure (one without an OUT parameter).
7. Your SELECT INTO is attempting to place multiple rows into a single-row variable.

Assuming your "function" is altered to provide the *maximum* similarity between the parameter and a random 10 TRACK_IDs it might look as follows:

```
create or replace function list_similar_tracks (
      frstTrack in tracks.track_id%type 
      ) return number is

   sim number;

begin

    select max(func_similarity(frstTrack, track_id)) into sim
      from tracks
     where rownum <= 10
           ;


   return sim;

end list_similar_tracks;
/
```

However, the name of the function seems to preclude that this is what you're actually attempting to do.

---

From your comments, your question is actually:

I have the following code; how do I print the top 10 function results? The current results are returned unsorted.

```
declare
   sim number;
begin

   for res in ( select * from tracks ) loop
      select * into sim 
        from ( select func_similarity(var1, var2) 
                 from dual 
                order by sim
                      )  
       order by sim;
   end loop;
end;
/
```

The problem with the above is firstly that you're ordering by the *variable* `sim`, which is NULL in the first instance but changes thereafter. However, the select from DUAL is only a *single* row, which means you're randomly ordering by a single row. This brings us back to my point at the top - use SQL where possible.

In this case you can simply SELECT from the table TRACKS and order by the function result. To do this you need to give the column created by your function result an alias (or order by the positional argument as already described in [Emmanuel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23132681/458741)).

For instance:

```
select func_similarity(var1, var2) as function_result
  from dual
```

Putting this together the code becomes:

```
begin

   for res in ( select *
                  from ( select func_similarity(variable, track_id) as f
                           from tracks
                          order by f desc
                                )
                 where rownum <= 10 ) loop
      -- do something
   end loop;

end;
/
```

Comment: the function that i was talking about is func_similarity, the procedure needs to stay as a procedure, func_similarity is used to compute the similarity between tracks, and i need to limit the output to 10 only, hence rownum <= 10, everything is working just fine, except i need to order by the number that is returned from the func_similarity function INSIDE the main procedure, doesn't amtter at this point if it's descending or ascending

Comment: But you're not outputting _anything_ @user2209644; you're "printing" to the terminal (assuming it's being run inside a terminal). Is this really what you want to do? Also, how many values do you want to use inside the procedure?

Comment: yes, for now my job is to debug the procedure and make sure the ouuput is ordered, just 10 values

Comment: It's still not 100% clear @user2209644... you want the least similar per row in the 10 rows of your TRACKS table or you want the 10 values per row in your TRACKS table?

Comment: okay so, lets say i have this tracks table, it contains over a thousand records, i then have the func_similarity function which works just fine, it returns a value ranging from 0.0 - 1.0, this procedure needs to take that function "func_similarity" take an id of a track, and compare that 1 track to ALL of the others, then order the list by the highest value returned by the similarity function and display the first 10.

Comment: this is great and very helpful, one last question, how do i store and display the result of this query?

Comment: The answer to that is up to you @user, how do you want to store and use it? What are you actually trying to do? It's the essence of asking a good question...

Comment: i am trying to show the result of that loop, so in the loop i would like to do something like dbms_output.put_line(res.track_id); however this throws a 302, track_id must be declared, i can't figure out where is everything kept, aren't the rows and values kept in the res?

Comment: You need to select the track_id as well @user2209644, `select track_id,  func_similarity(variable, track_id) as f from tracks`

Answer (score 0):

You have a query using a function, let's say something like:

```
select t.field1, t.field2, ..., function1(t.field1), ...
from table1 t
where ...
```

Oracle supports `order by` clause with column indexes, i.e. if the field returned by the function is the nth one in the select (here, `field1` is in position 1, `field2` in position 2), you just have to add:

```
order by n
```

For instance:

```
select t.field1, function1(t.field1) c2
from table1 t
where ...
order by 2 /* 2 being the index of the column computed by the function */
```